# How to loop int 1 according to a number variable

Tags: php

What would be the best way in php to loop int 1 a number of times equal to a number value variable.

Let's say I have a variable that equals 5
The loop would be 1,1,1,1,1
5 times 1
Thanks

Comment: `for( $i=0; $i < $VAR; $i++){}`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Use `trim(str_repeat("1,",5),',')`  [Live demo](https://eval.in/1053348)

Answer (score 0):

use While loop:

example:

```
$var = 5;
$i = 0;
while ($i != $var) {
  $i++;
}
```